# Как изменить интервал у таймера?

Tags: c#

Не подскажете, как изменить интервал у таймера?
Происходит вот это действие по заданному интервалу `timer1.Interval = 10000;`

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

Но, когда я интервал изменяю на другое значение, то событие происходит опять с интервалом 10000, + происходит ещё одно событие уже с другим интервалом.

Посоветуйте мне что-нибудь.
timer1.Interval = 120000;
Так и изменяю интервал.

Comment: Можно подробнее код, где Вы изменяете интервал?

Comment: Попробуй сначала нажми F6, а потом F5, т.е. собери проект.

Answer (score 1):

В своем проекте я делал вот так:

```
StateChangeTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ExecuteStateChange);
```

В методе ExecuteStateChange я писал вот так

```
StateChangeTimer.Interval = time * 1000;
```

Использовал System.Timers.

Comment: Попробуйте установить таймеру свойство AutoReset:
StateChangeTimer.AutoReset = true;